# Solve A System of Trigonometric Equations

Tags: equation-solving, functions, complex, trigonometry, periodic-function

I tried running the following code on Mathematica Cloud, but it didn't because it was taking long of I have the basic plan. Would someone please run this code for me and share with me the results. it's a system of two trigonometric equations. I'm expecting the solutions to be infinite. Also is the code okay the way it is? Your help would be much appreciated:

```
FindRoot[{(4.566810^(-3))(
  (2.71828^(-1.5812x+0.000599221y))*Cos[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y]+
  (2.71828^(-1.5812x-0.000599221y))*Cos[( 0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y])+
  (0.499969927)(
  (-2.71828^(-1.5812x+0.000599221y))*Sin[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y]+
  ( 2.71828^(-1.5812x-0.000599221y))*Sin[( 0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y])==-0.4908672,
  (4.566810^(-3))(
  (2.71828^(-1.5812x+0.000599221y))*Sin[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y]+
  (2.71828^(-1.5812x-0.000599221y))*Sin[( 0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)Log[2.71828]y])+
  (0.499969927)(
  ( 2.71828^(-1.5812x+0.000599221y))*Cos[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y]+
  (-2.71828^(-1.5812x-0.000599221y))*Cos[( 0.000599221)*Log[2.71828]x+(-1.5812)*Log[2.71828]y])==-8.342010^(-5)},{{x,1},{y,1}}]
```

Comment: You are on the ragged edge of having people downvote and close your question. I took the liberty of editing your post to indent your code to make it clear. Next, you are using `()` and `{}` interchangeably. That is VERY bad. Those mean completely different things to Mathematica. Please change all `{}` to `()` except if you are using a list of items.  Next you have `Log[2.71828]` in 16 places. I'm guessing you are trying to say "natural log", but `Log` means "natural log" in Mathematica unless you do something special. And check/fix open and close `[]` on those. Then try `FindRoot` instead.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I tried using FindRoot and it doesn't give an output, why is that?

Comment: @Thando - edit your question to include the corrections and show how you used `FindRoot`.

Comment: @Bob- I just did the corrections. What am I doing wrong that's causing the lack of output? Thanks

Comment: @Bob- Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Bob-I tried to run the code you edited and I did not get an output for the contour plot and when I run the FindRoot it gives an error. I'm using a trial version of Mathematica on a hp laptop. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {(4.566810^(-3)) ((2.71828^(-1.5812 x + 0.000599221 y))*
         Cos[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[2.71828] y] + (2.71828^(-1.5812 x - 0.000599221 y))*
         Cos[(0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[
             2.71828] y]) + (0.499969927) ((-2.71828^(-1.5812 x + 
              0.000599221 y))*
         Sin[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[2.71828] y] + (2.71828^(-1.5812 x - 0.000599221 y))*
         Sin[(0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[
             2.71828] y]) == -0.4908672, (4.566810^(-3)) ((2.71828^(-1.5812 x \
+ 0.000599221 y))*
         Sin[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[2.71828] y] + (2.71828^(-1.5812 x - 0.000599221 y))*
         Sin[(0.000599221)*
            Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812) Log[
             2.71828] y]) + (0.499969927) ((2.71828^(-1.5812 x + 
             0.000599221 y))*
         Cos[(-0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[2.71828] y] + (-2.71828^(-1.5812 x - 0.000599221 y))*
         Cos[(0.000599221)*Log[2.71828] x + (-1.5812)*
            Log[2.71828] y]) == -8.342010^(-5)};
```

[`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) needs good initial estimates. Plotting is often useful.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqns, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Use the intersections to estimate the solutions

```
FindRoot[eqns, {{x, -2}, {y, #}}] & /@ Range[-6, 10, 4]

(* {{x -> -2.02027, y -> -6.07562}, {x -> -2.02979, 
  y -> -2.02563}, {x -> -2.02979, y -> 2.02556}, {x -> -2.02027, 
  y -> 6.07556}, {x -> -2.00207, y -> 10.1222}} *)
```

If your use of `2.71828` is intended to be `E`, use `E` throughout. Then `Log[E]` is just `1`